# Scraping data from yahoo finance using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrap last 5 days data from yahoo finance. [Here is the link](https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/20MICRONS.NS/history?period1=1489775400&period2=1490207400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d) but I'm not getting any data. The result give everything except the generated data.
This is what I tried:

```
url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/20MICRONS.NS/history?period1=1199125800&period2=1490207400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"
request = urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 0):

Finance data is not embedded to the web page it is loaded by JavaScript. As you scroll down the page you will see website loading to new data to the page. The best way to solve this problem is to use `selenium` or `PhantomJS` like solutions.
You can use them with `python`.